# Create Polygon in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still learning SQL. I need to create two rectangles based on the length and width I insert into the table. I'm then running a simple stored procedure to update the table.

```
  Create Table Field (
  FieldId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
  FieldLength INT NOT NULL,
  FieldWidth INT NOT NULL,
  FieldHalfLength INT NULL,
  LeftHalfField GEOMETRY NULL,
  RightHalfField GEOMETRY NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO Field (FieldLength, FieldWidth) VALUES (4134, 2678);
```

Stored Procedure

```
  Update Field
  Set 
  FieldHalfLength = (FieldLength/2),
  LeftHalfField = Polygon(0 0, FieldHalfLength 0, FieldHalfLength FieldWidth, 0 FieldWidth, 0 0),
  RightHalfField = Polygon(FieldHalfLength 0, FieldLength 0, FieldLength FieldWidth, FieldHalfLength 
  FieldWidth, FieldHalfLength 0);
```

I can't figure out how to create the polygon for LeftHalfField and RightHalfField. Let me know if there's a simple solution to this problem. It would also be helpful if I need to approach this a different way.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Is polygon a built-in function?)

Comment: Just Microsoft SSMS. I thought Polygon was a built-in function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/polygon?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It is not, at least not like that -- `GEOMETRY` functions are only valid inside `GEOMETRY` strings. Unfortunately T-SQL offers no convenience methods for creating these strings from typed data, you'll just have to `CONCAT` stuff together before feeding it to `STPolyFromText`/`Parse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating POLYGON as if it were a function, but it is not. With MS SQL server spatial data is not an easy task IMHO (postgreSQL and postGIS looks more appealing on that). 'POLYGON((...))' is a geometry string that is parsed by MS SQL server. In your case, ie:

```
CREATE TABLE Field
  (
    FieldId         INT      IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , FieldLength     INT      NOT NULL
  , FieldWidth      INT      NOT NULL
  , FieldHalfLength AS FieldLength / 2
  , LeftHalfField   GEOMETRY NULL
  , RightHalfField  GEOMETRY NULL
  );

INSERT INTO Field(FieldLength, FieldWidth)VALUES(4134, 2678);



UPDATE
  Field
SET
  LeftHalfField='POLYGON(( 0 0,'+CAST(FieldHalfLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0, '
                +CAST(FieldHalfLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' '+CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+', 0 '
                +CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+', 0 0))'
, RightHalfField='POLYGON(('+CAST(FieldHalfLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0, '
                 +CAST(FieldLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0,'+CAST(FieldLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' '
                 +CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+','+CAST(FieldHalfLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' '
                 +CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+','+CAST(FieldHalfLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0))';

SELECT * FROM dbo.Field;
```

EDIT: You could as well do it all with computed columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Field
  (
    FieldId         INT      IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , FieldLength     INT      NOT NULL
  , FieldWidth      INT      NOT NULL
  , FieldHalfLength AS FieldLength / 2
  , LeftHalfField  AS CAST('POLYGON(( 0 0,'+CAST((FieldLength / 2) AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0, '
                +CAST((FieldLength / 2) AS VARCHAR(10))+' '+CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+', 0 '
                +CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+', 0 0))' AS GEOMETRY),
   RightHalfField AS cast('POLYGON(('+CAST((FieldLength / 2) AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0, '
                 +CAST(FieldLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0,'+CAST(FieldLength AS VARCHAR(10))+' '
                 +CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+','+CAST((FieldLength / 2) AS VARCHAR(10))+' '
                 +CAST(FieldWidth AS VARCHAR(10))+','+CAST((FieldLength / 2) AS VARCHAR(10))+' 0))' AS GEOMETRY)
  );

INSERT INTO Field(FieldLength, FieldWidth)VALUES(4134, 2678);
SELECT * FROM dbo.Field;
```

Comment: Gack. At least use `CONCAT` so you can get rid of all the `CAST`s (`CONCAT` casts implicitly).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, what is "Gack"? And BTW I don't care abput getting rid of cast.

Comment: Alright -- if you really think that's more readable than (e.g.) `CONCAT('POLYGON(( 0 0,', FieldLength / 2, ' 0, ', FieldLength / 2, ' ', FieldWidth, ', 0 ', FieldWidth, ', 0 0))')` we just have widely differing tastes, I suppose. (I'd actually prefer `REPLACE(REPLACE('POLYGON(( 0 0, $HalfFieldLength 0, $HalfFieldLength $FieldWidth, 0 $FieldWidth, 0 0))', '$HalfFieldLength', FieldLength / 2), '$FieldWidth', FieldWidth)`, even if nesting gets uncomfortable.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, as you said, it is just a matter of taste, that doesn't have any effect on the result. (and you still didn't tell what you meant by "gack", hope it was not meant to do an insult).

Comment: No. "Gack" is an onomatopoeia for the sound you make when you see something nasty, as in, "I most definitely do not like the way this code looks". My opinion of the esthetics of this code in no way reflects on you (or at least it isn't intended to do so).

Comment: And here I was, thinking it means "Greatness acknowledged".

Comment: @JeroenMostert, OK. I don't use Concat() personally, as I don't see it providing anything useful for me. I would like something like a string interpolation that exists in many languages like $'POLYGON((0 0, {FieldLength/2} 0, ...))'.

Comment: `CONCAT` has two big advantages over `+` in scenarios where you're concatenating a lot: it concatenates `NULL` as the empty string and it auto-converts to `CHAR` without casts. The closest thing you can get to something like string interpolation is the nested `REPLACE` solution I gave; I prefer this even over the `CONCAT` solution because the string remains "whole" and it's easy to spot any mistakes, with the only drawback being that you have to chain up another `REPLACE` for each value you want to interpolate. Maybe one day T-SQL will move on from the 1970s and get real string processing...

Comment: @JeroenMostert, no, replace can't even come close to string interpolation. Maybe I wasn't clear. Expecting too much from t-sql. If I needed this often enough, I would simply create a CLR function for that.